# Pattern generation based on data frame in R

Tags: r, paste

I am looking to generate a pattern based on some columns of a data frame.
Sample data set could be :

```
domain <- c('ebay.com','facebook.com','auto.com')
id <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
cost <- c(0.82,0.40,0.57)
rand_val <- c(0000807,0000808,0000809)
test_data <- data.frame(domain,id,cost,rand_val)
```

Based on COLUMNS of test_data i am looking to generate this pattern as text output:

```
if every domain = "ebay.com", id in (21000):
  rand_val:0000807
cost: 0.82
elif every domain = "facebook.com", id in (23400):
  rand_val:0000808
cost: 0.40
elif every domain = "auto.com", id in (26800):
  rand_val:0000809
cost: 0.57
```

How can i iterate based on number of rows in the data frame to produce this pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  use `paste` with `sep` and `collapse` for this:

```
res <- paste('if every domain = "',test_data$domain, '", id in (', test_data$id, '):
  rand_val:', test_data$rand_val, '
cost: ', test_data$cost, sep="", collapse = "
el")
cat(res)

if every domain = "ebay.com", id in (21000):
  rand_val:807
cost: 0.82
elif every domain = "facebook.com", id in (23400):
  rand_val:808
cost: 0.4
elif every domain = "auto.com", id in (26800):
  rand_val:809
cost: 0.57
```

Comment: `if every domain = \"ebay.com\", id in (21000):\n  rand_val:807\ncost: 0.82\nelif every domain = \"facebook.com\", id in (23400):\n  rand_val:808\ncost: 0.4\nelif every domain = \"auto.com\", id in (26800):\n  rand_val:809\ncost: 0.57` this is what i get based your input, so i am getting a \n instead of a new line , and also this: \"ebay.com\", \"facebook.com\" as domains. can you help tweaking your code to produce the desirable result.

Comment: Yes this works perfectly, Thanks. However i saw we can use cat() function as well , which produces the same result.`cat(paste('if every domain = "',test_data$domain, '", id in (', test_data$id, '):\nrand_val:', test_data$rand_val, '\ncost: ', test_data$cost, sep="", collapse = "
el"))`. Anyways thanks for the help.